# Properties of first integral in ode

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Let $\frac{dx}{dt}=Z(x) $ be an ode in an open subset $U\subset\mathbb{R}^n$, I'm strugling to show the follow statements:

i) For every point $p\in U$, such that $Z(p)\neq0$, there is a neighbor $V_p$ of $p$, such that the ode adimits first integral on $V_p$.

ii) If $U$ is simply connected and $div(Z)=0$, then the ode adimits first integral.

To the first part, I think that the obvious path is try to build the first integral, but I can't see how to do it. I also have tried to proof by contradiction, but I can't get the result.

Thanks in advance.